# Scala Error: type exists, but it has no companion object

Tags: scala, user-defined-types, companion-object

I have defined a type inside a package object as following in package.scala.

```
type Structure = List [(int, int)]
```

Now I want to use this Structure inside a class in abc.scala and get the elements of the list individually. abc.scala and package.scala are inside the same folder (src/utility).

```
class abc (d: Structure) {
  val a = d._1
  val b = d._2
  ...................
  ...................
}
```

It compiles, but I need to try a test inside another folder (test). I have imported the package utility in the test code as follows.

```
import utility._
class test {
  val a = utility.Structure ((1, 2), (2, 5))
  ............................
  ............................
}
```

I am getting the following error:
object Structure is not a member of package src.utility.
Note: type Structure exists, but it has no companion object.

How do I define the companion object of the type? I need to use the type in the class abc.

Comment: sometimes the error message is misleading a little, since there can be two places, where a **type with the same local** name is defined, and if you look for a companion object for x and see one, potentially, there is another x somewhere in the project structure which hasn't a companion object (so it has been in my case), and this one instead is triggering the error. if the error message would mention the whole package path, could be more clear sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

So, it sounds like you have something like this:

```
package src
package object utility {
  type Structure = List[(Int, Int)]
}
```

To get what you want, simply add `val Structure = List`. So, it'd look like this:

```
package src
package object utility {
  type Structure = List[(Int, Int)]
  val Structure = List
}
```

Now, `Structure((1, 2))` will work as long as you import your package.

Comment: Yes it worked. That was so easy. Thank you very much.

Comment: No prob, but there's a catch: you can also do stuff like `Structure("foo")`, and that will return a List[String]. Just an FYI! If that's a deal breaker, let me know...maybe we can come up with something better.

Comment: Now I have a different problem. I have defined a "Indep_<" operation in class abc with the two Structures as input. I want to test that in my test file. But it is saying: value Indep_< is not a member of List[Int, Int].

Comment: I don't follow...could you post a little code snippet of the "Indep_<" operation?